# Is there any good reason not to use 'define' with variable argument length?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

Recently I came upon this code:

```
#define LOG(type, str)                      printf(str)
#define LOG1(type, str,arg1)                printf(str,arg1)
#define LOG2(type, str,arg1,arg2)           printf(str,arg1,arg2)
#define LOG3(type, str,arg1,arg2,arg3)      printf(str,arg1,arg2,arg3)
#define LOG4(type, str,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4) printf(str,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
```

The code was written recently. So I guess it can be compiled with C99.

My question is: Why not use a simple macro with variable arguments length? We would just limit ourselves to `LOG` macro and nothing more. Not to mention that we won't have to add `LOG5`, `LOG6`, etc. Would something terrible happen if we get a stack trace, run out of memory, anything that would make this solution useful?

I am a minimalist, if we can get fewer lines the better. But am I missing something here? Was this intentional or it is a bad coding practice?

Comment: AFAIK if the code is not targeted at C99 then that's the only way you could have written the macro. Also: I don't know why on earth this is not a function.

Comment: @Jon, assuming you dont want logs in release builds, you can save on the whole function call affair. Lets no go `__naked__`. Oh, and this would also wipe all those string literals for log lines

Comment: @RomanSaveljev: You 'd have to convince me that saving on the function calls *matters* first. :-)

Comment: @Jon There is no way of getting the `__LINE__` of the call without macros unless you write it into every invocation and it can be unnerving to write `log(__FILE__, __LINE__, ...)` every time.

Comment: @Jon Oh-oh.. I have proper spell prepared just for such an encounter: Pipeline-flush! Cache-miss! No-guarantee-for-function-inlining! Cadabra!!

Comment: @RedX: That sounds legit, although if the log messages are distinct it shouldn't be necessary. But point taken.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev: Is this a CPU-bound application? Because if it isn't, you can `usleep` for 10msec before logging and noone might notice.

Comment: @Jon, sorry, I come from embedded systems background.. It is like photosensibilization - some specific stimulus just triggers uncontrolled response :) I value "universal solutions", no matter how scarce they could be. I guess, doing logging by macros is one of those. It does not hurt to save 10msec, if the result is the code done in a way expected by many.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev: That's a fair point (obviously I have a very different background so I see things differently too).

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor support for variadic macros looks to me the only good reason. We had for decades in our project `LOG, LOG1 etc`, but did upgrade to `...` recently.

As per wikipedia:

> Several compilers support variable-argument macros when compiling C and C++ code: the GNU Compiler Collection 3.0,[2] Visual Studio 2005,[3] C++Builder 2006, and Oracle Solaris Studio (formerly Sun Studio) Forte Developer 6 update 2 (C++ version 5.3).[5] GCC also supports such macros when compiling Objective-C.

If you know your platform, then use fancy variadic macros. If there are few to support, then things could turn out to be more interesting